# Extract fields from Json using Kusto in Application Insights

Tags: json, parsing, azure-application-insights, kql

I have the following json contained in a particular field in the traces.customDimensions:

[image]

When I parse this Json to extract a particular value I always get an empty column, for example:

```
traces | order by timestamp desc
| project CurrentContext = parse_json(customDimensions.CurrentPluginContext)
| extend Source = CurrentContext.source
| project Source
```

The query returns the following:

[image]

I've also tried:

```
traces | order by timestamp desc
| project timestamp, CurrentContext = customDimensions.CurrentPluginContext, CurrentParentContext = customDimensions.CurrentParentluginContext,
Source = parse_json(tostring(customDimensions.CurrentPluginContext)).source,
DepthCurrentContext = parse_json(tostring(customDimensions.CurrentPluginContext)).depth,
DepthCurrentParentContext = parse_json(tostring(customDimensions.CurrentParentluginContext)).depth
| mv-expand CurrentContext
| extend Source = CurrentContext.source
```

But here I get also an empty "Source" column. And the Columns "DepthCurrentContext" and "DepthCurrentParentContext" do not even appear.

[image]

**The Json is valid.**

Do I miss something here?

Any help is very appreciated!

**UPDATE 27.02.2023**

When I do the following:

```
let json = '{"source": "GetUserData","correlationId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","depth": "1","initiatingUserId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","isInTransaction": "False","isolationMode": "2","message": "Update","mode": "Asynchronus","operationId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","orgId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","orgName": "unqXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","requestId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","userId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","entityId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","entityName": "systemuser","type": "Plugin","stage": "Post-operation"}';

traces
| extend properties = parse_json(json)
| project Source = properties.source, CorrelationID = properties.correlationId
```

I get the properties out of the Json. The Json is the exact same as the ohne from the log.

Any idea?

Comment: Please try `| extend Source = tostring(parse_json(CurrentContext).source)`

Comment: Thx for the suggestion but still the "Source" column is empty

Answer (score 4):

as mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parsejsonfunction): you will need to use `tostring` on the internal property bag.

i.e. `parse_json(tostring(parse_json(customDimensions).CurrentPluginContext))`

[image]

Comment: Hi @Yoni L. Thank you for this hint but unfortunately I dont eben get columns when I do this:

traces
| where customDimensions.CurrentPluginContext != ""
| order by timestamp desc
| extend CurrentContext = parse_json(tostring(parse_json(customDimensions).CurrentPluginContext))
| project CurrentContext.source

Answer (score 0):

```
traces | order by timestamp desc
| project CurrentContext = parse_json(customDimensions.CurrentPluginContext)
| extend Source = parse_json(tostring(CurrentContext)).source
| project Source
```

Comment: thx for the suggestion but still empty