# How could I parse the json array in Kusto?

Tags: arrays, json, parsing, kql, appinsights

How could I parse the json array in Kusto?

Here is what I tried:

```
customEvents
| where name == "myname"
| project a = parse_json(customDimensions.Content)
| extend b = a[0].Section;
```

[image]

But as you can see the `b` still remains empty and never gets initialized to the `Section` value. While, according to [the KQL documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parsejsonfunction) it should work.

Comment: please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75582815/7861807